# SQL - how to show SKUs with the lowest price from a query

Tags: sql, qsqlquery

I am making a query for a price comparison site and I have to provide them a csv file with certain data. I have done the query and the first problem was that the prices that showed up in it were the full prices from sql database. So when we have for example a discount applied to the whole category of products the price shown is still the full price not the discounted one. I solved that by checking if an SKU is in a discounted category and the query calculates the price accordingly.

The new problem is now that a query checks through categories and if one sku is in multiple categories it creates a row with same SKU for each category and I end up with multiple rows with same SKU and only one has correct price (discounted one).

Example query result. NOTE that the Price column is a calculated result not the data from the table.

| SKU | Product | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Ball | 19 |
| A | Ball | 19 |
| A | Ball | 15 |
| B | Cube | 10 |
| B | Cube | 8 |

How do I filter it to just this

| SKU | Product | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Ball | 15 |
| B | Cube | 8 |

Comment: Please show query that you used.

Comment: If a product 'Ball' for 20$ is in categories 'Toys' and 'Sports', and toys are discounted by 5% and sport articles are discounted by 10%, what price do you want to show for the ball?

Comment: You have tagged two different DBMS: MySQL and SQL Server. Which one are you using? Please tag only the DBMS that you are using.

Comment: I've removed the conflicting tag. [Edit] your question to retag the correct RDBMS,

Answer (score 0):

You need GROUP BY with aggregate function MIN()

```
SELECT SKU
     , Product
     , MIN(Price) as Price
  FROM <table>
 GROUP
    BY SKU
     , Product
```

Comment: I do not think that will work because there is only  one Price in the table, I have a CASE where I have to check if SKU is in certain category and then if it is it calculates the new price.